# Как узнать активна ли страница/вкладка браузера?

Tags: javascript

Имеется некоторая страница, на ней отображается окно с сообщениями.
Как определить активна ли сейчас страница (т.е. она на переднем плане в `Windows` или нет)?
Пробовала следить за фокусом окна с помощью

```
window.onfocus = function(){ isFocus = true; }
window.onblur = function(){ isFocus = false; }
```

В ff отрабатывает, в хроме -если фокус переходит на какой-нибудь элемент страницы, то onblur все равно вызывается, хотя страница так и есть на переднем плане в `Windows`.
Посоветуйте как быть?

Answer (score 4):

Работает в Chrome. Нужно заметить что для того, чтоб событие активировалось, необходимо не просто перейти на вкладку, а действительно щелкнуть по области *body* страницы для того, что окно было в фокусе.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            window.focus();

            $(window).bind('focus', function() {
                console.log("focus!");
            });

            $(window).bind('blur', function() {
                console.log("blur!");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вот еще http://jsfiddle.net/KuZSu/ пример со StackOverflow

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!document.hidden){
   console.log("открыта");
}
else { 
   console.log("закрыта");
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: а `if-else` лесенкой вот так писать, да еще и без фигурных скобок...причем в if'е в две строки а в else в одну...это какой-то новый Code Style Conventions?